# How to write a function that returns an array of objects using a custom interface type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I am trying to create a function that pushes out an object to an array while using an interface type.

This is what I have so far, but I am getting an error of `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Customer'`

These are the steps I've taken and that I need to follow:

1. Declare an array variable of type 'Customer'
2. The function must accept one object of type 'Customer'.
3. The function return type MUST be an array of 'Customer'.
4. Inside the function, add the object passed to the function to the array.
5. Function MUST return the array.

```js
// Create Customer interface
interface Customer {
  name: string
  id: number
}

// 1. Declare an array variable of type 'Customer'
let customer: Customer[] = []

// 2. Create a f(n) that accepts one objec of type 'Customer'
function addCustomer(person: Customer): Customer {
  // 3. Add the object to the customer array
  return customer.push(person.name, person.id)
}

const customer1 = {
  name: 'molly',
  id: 101,
}

console.log(addCustomer(customer1))


/*Sample Output:

[  { name: 'molly', id: 101 } ] 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on `Array.prototype.push` type signature:

```js
Array<T>.push(...items: T[]): number
```

In your case:

```js
Array<Customer>.push(...items: Customer[]): number
```

Also take a look on the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

`push` expects a `Customer` argument whether you are passing `person.name`. It is not correct.

You should pass `Customer` object:

```js
function addCustomer(person: Customer) {
  // 3. Add the object to the customer array
  return customer.push(person)
}
```

Furthermore, `push` returns new length of the array instead of passed element. It means that `push` returns `number` whether you want to return `Customer` from the `addCustomer`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not following your third requirement:

> The function return type MUST be an array of 'Customer'.

According to it, your function should return an array. Your function signature however says that it returns a single `Customer` instead of `Customer[]`. Your function should be typed as follows instead:

```
function addCustomer(person: Customer): Customer[] {
  return customer.push(person);
}
```

The error now becomes `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Customer[]'`. You're returning the result of [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), which according to the documentation returns "*The new length property of the object upon which the method was called*" which is a number, not the array. For it to match your specification, it should return the array instead:

```
function addCustomer(person: Customer): Customer[] {
  customer.push(person);
  return customer; // I would advise renaming this to the plural `customers` instead
}
```

After that the function matches the expected behavior.

**Please note** that the entire benefit of TypeScript is that these kinds of errors can be caught at compile time or even *as you type*. Using a modern code editor you could've hovered over the `push` method to see what kind of data it expects and returns (a `number` in this case, and not the `Customer[]` you're expecting).